# React-router location state object is empty

Tags: reactjs, react-router, history

I`m trying to persist state with react-router using a DateObject object from react-multi-date-picker library: https://shahabyazdi.github.io/react-multi-date-picker/date-object/ . But the object is emptied when I try to access the state after navigating.

```
let history = useHistory();
history.replace({pathname: "/", state: {date: new DateObject()});
history.push({pathname: "/another-path"});
```

```
let history = useHistory();
history.goBack();
```

```
let location = useLocation();
console.log(location.state.date);
```

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function Router() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/">
          <CustomDatePicker />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/another-path">
          <AnotherComponent />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default Router;
```

**Before navigating**

[image: state before navigating]

**After navigating**

[image: state after navigating]

Comment: That value Is being passed as prop to the component referred at /

Comment: tried to access the props, but the object seems empty after navigating. like the pictures I posted.

Comment: Maybe you can try something like: <Route
  path='/dashboard'
  render={(props) => (
    <Dashboard {...props} isAuthed={true} />
  )}
/>

Comment: Can you share the code for the component that handles the "/" route?

Comment: I added the router component above

Comment: I have a similar Problem: Once I use an Object, created through a class-definition (tried with custom and with Decimal from Decimal.js-package) the location.state provided by useLocation is null. 
But I realized, that it still works with primitive objects (js key-value-pairs, with only primitive typed values like strings or numbers. TS-enums also work)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new state which is defined by `new DateObject()` and pass that through instead. So for example

```
this.setState({myNewState: new DateObject()})
// then pass it through
history.replace({pathname: "/", state: {date: myNewState});
```

or useState if its a functional component.

Hope that works

Comment: if I put any other object, string, number... it works fine, but when I put this "new DateObject()" things become weird.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution! I used the method `toDate()` in the **react-multi-date-picker** library to convert the custom DateObject to javascript Date object and store it in state. For some reason, storing the DateObject() in the history stack, navigating away and coming back doesn't work! Thanks!